# Change datatype in Array[StructField] at an index spark-shell/ scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I created an Array[StructField] of length 8 in spark-shell.
Now, I want to edit the datatype of one of the fields.
Code:

```
val fields = header.map(field_name => StructField(field_name, IntegerType, true))
```

'header' is a schema string I created.

In python/ pyspark, to edit column datatype at index 5, the following code worked.

```
fields[5].dataType = StringType()
```

How do I achieve it in scala/spark-shell? I tried the following two codes but did not work.

```
fields(5).dataType = StringType

fields(5).update(1, StringType)
```

I just got started with scala. Thank you and appreciate any help.

Comment: May I ask why do you need this? It looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). One way or another - `DataTypes` are immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
fields(5) = fields(5).copy(dataType=StringType)
```